# Java Hibernate: Session.get never returns a result

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm just learning how to use Hibernate for database modeling/mapping. I'm using the following code snippet to get a User model.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
User user = (User) session.get(User.class, id);
session.close();
```

The user's configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 2.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-2.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="c3.data.User">
            <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
                    <generator class="identity"/>
            </id>
            <property name="username" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <property name="password" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <property name="email" type="java.lang.String"/>
            <property name="salt" type="java.lang.String"/>

            <one-to-one name="authSession" property-ref="user" class="c3.data.AuthSession"/>
            <set name="projects" inverse="true">
                    <key column="projectLeadId"/>
                    <one-to-many class="c3.data.Project"/>
            </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

As you can see, it holds a relationship to other models called AuthSession and Project. I can post their configuration files if necessary.

The problem I'm having is when I call Session.get(), it never returns; it just hangs. Hibernate shows me the queries, and it runs the query for the User, the AuthSession, and the Projects. Apart from not confirming the values of the parameters, the queries look correct. After the queries for the Projects, nothing happens. I put a print statement right after the call for get and it never gets printed.

I don't know what else to check to see what might be going wrong. Any thoughts?

**Edit:**
There was an exception, here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2314)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:664)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:999)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:878)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2094)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1801)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:661)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1014)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1977)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3821)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1075)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2421)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:971)
    at c3.data.UserManager.getUser(UserManager.java:22)
    at c3.data.AuthSessionManager.sessionExists(AuthSessionManager.java:14)
    at c3.console.Server.logon(Server.java:289)
    at c3.console.Server.onToken(Server.java:242)
    at tokenwebsocket.server.TokenWebSocketServer.onMessage(TokenWebSocketServer.java:37)
    at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer.onWebsocketMessage(WebSocketServer.java:457)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.deliverMessage(WebSocketImpl.java:561)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decodeFrames(WebSocketImpl.java:328)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.decode(WebSocketImpl.java:149)
    at org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer$WebSocketWorker.run(WebSocketServer.java:593)
```

Comment: did you check the SQL output? Any activity on the db logs/tracer?

Comment: Sounds like an exception is being thrown. Have you tried putting it in a try catch and seeing if `HibernateException` is being thrown?

Comment: It would help to see how your dataSource and sessionFactory are configured.

Comment: So, "it just hangs", if the application becomes unresponsive take a few Thread Dumps and check if there are any monitors being locked: http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/TakeThreadDump.html. You can parse the TDs with this tool: http://java.net/projects/threadlogic/